# How to perform Set Operations in C++?

Tags: c++, set, set-intersection

I am a second year student trying to complete a project assigned by a really crappy professor. She taught us how to perform set intersection and symmetric difference inside of Bash, but when it comes to C++ I am lost.

Attached is the code currently in my project. The context is that based on a given file, movies are imported and actors are found. I know my file is reading correctly, as I have tested it multiple ways.

Also attached is a copy of the way she describes set operations. Please help!

[image]

```
cout << "Actors in both movies are: " << endl;
set<string> intersect;

set_intersection(actors_in_movie1.begin(), actors_in_movie1.end(), actors_in_movie2.begin(), actors_in_movie2.end(), inserter(intersect, intersect.begin()));
for(auto j = intersect.begin(); j != intersect.end(); j++)
{
    cout << *j << endl;
}
```

Comment: why not use system("command"); and let the bash do the rest??
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/system-call-in-c/

Comment: You mean this set_intersection => http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/ ? What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not sure how you have defined `actors_in_movie1` and `actors_in_movie2`, but the code looks ok for doing set_intersection.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference

Comment: @AshwinSubramanya: Using `system` for that is a bad idea in so many ways that I can't list them all here in the space of a single comment.

Comment: @Jacob: Are you familiar with Venn diagrams? You may want to draw the Venn diagrams for the three operations.

Comment: @MSalters Im sorry Back here in India(education system) the focus is on getting the result first then think of optimizations so i gave most crude solution.

Comment: Aside: You don't need to store the intersection, you can pass `std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout)` to stream it out as it is created.

Comment: That problem statement is also suspect, I don't think "2. If option is C or c" related to "If the user chooses option 2" as one talks about pairs of movies, and the other talks about all movies relating to a particular actor.

Comment: FYI, if your question has been answered, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

If you sort your input ranges, you can use the [`std::set_union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union), [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection), and [`std::set_symmetric_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference) algorithms in the `algorithm` header.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <cassert>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> a1{{"A", "B", "C"}};
    std::vector<std::string> a2{{"B", "C", "D", "F", "X"}};

    assert(std::is_sorted(a1.begin(), a1.end()));
    assert(std::is_sorted(a2.begin(), a2.end()));

    std::set<std::string> union_;
    std::set_union(a1.begin(), a1.end(), a2.begin(), a2.end(), 
                   std::inserter(union_, union_.begin()));

    std::set<std::string> intersection;
    std::set_intersection(a1.begin(), a1.end(), a2.begin(), a2.end(), 
                          std::inserter(intersection, intersection.begin()));

    std::set<std::string> symmetric_diff;
    std::set_symmetric_difference(a1.begin(), a1.end(), a2.begin(), a2.end(), 
                                  std::inserter(symmetric_diff, symmetric_diff.begin()));
}
```

Working example at https://ideone.com/dW9AkT :

```
a1: A, B, C, 
a2: B, C, D, F, X, 

union: A, B, C, D, F, X, 
intersection: B, C, 
symmetric_difference: A, D, F, X,
```